# Ruby: calculate average() while excluding nil values from data

Tags: ruby, null

I'm very new to Ruby and I'm having some difficulties with a seemingly simple problem.

Code is here...

https://github.com/sensu/sensu-community-plugins/blob/master/plugins/graphite/check-stats.rb

...but I've included a full copy of the current source at the end, because it may change as new versions are submitted to Github.

It's a Sensu plugin. It collects data from Graphite via an HTTP request. Stores the reply in body, which is then JSON.parse() into data.

For each metric in data, it collects datapoints, and performs an average on the datapoints. If average is higher than certain thresholds (options -w or -c), it throws a warning or a critical.

Sometimes the Graphite store is a bit behind times. The most recent data point may be missing from some metrics. When that happens, the data point is nil.

The problem is, nil is counted as zero when computing average(datapoints). This artificially lowers the average, sometimes to the effect that the plugin doesn't trigger when it should.

What's the best way to eliminate the nil values from the calculation of average?

Ideally, the elimination of the nils should happen in such a way that, if all data points are nil, then it should trigger the datapoints.empty condition. Basically, kill all the nils before they reach "unless datapoints.empty?" because if all are nil then we don't actually have any data points.

Or somehow metric.collect{} should skip the nil values.

I've tried to use .compact but that didn't seem to make a difference (probably I've used it wrong).

---

This is the current version of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

#
# Checks metrics in graphite, averaged over a period of time.
#
# The fired sensu event will only be critical if a stat is
# above the critical threshold. Otherwise, the event will be warning,
# if a stat is above the warning threshold.
#
# Multiple stats will be checked if * are used
# in the "target" query.
#
# Author: Alan Smith (alan@asmith.me)
# Date: 08/28/2014
#

require 'rubygems' if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9.0'
require 'json'
require 'net/http'
require 'sensu-plugin/check/cli'

class CheckGraphiteStat < Sensu::Plugin::Check::CLI

  option :host,
    :short => "-h HOST",
    :long => "--host HOST",
    :description => "graphite hostname",
    :proc => proc {|p| p.to_s },
    :default => "graphite"

  option :period,
    :short => "-p PERIOD",
    :long => "--period PERIOD",
    :description => "The period back in time to extract from Graphite. Use -24hours, -2days, -15mins, etc, same format as in Graphite",
    :proc => proc {|p| p.to_s },
    :required => true

  option :target,
    :short => "-t TARGET",
    :long => "--target TARGET",
    :description => "The graphite metric name. Can include * to query multiple metrics",
    :proc => proc {|p| p.to_s },
    :required => true

  option :warn,
    :short => "-w WARN",
    :long => "--warn WARN",
    :description => "Warning level",
    :proc => proc {|p| p.to_f },
    :required => false

  option :crit,
    :short => "-c Crit",
    :long => "--crit CRIT",
    :description => "Critical level",
    :proc => proc {|p| p.to_f },
    :required => false

  def average(a)
    total = 0
    a.to_a.each {|i| total += i.to_f}

    total / a.length
  end

  def danger(metric)
    datapoints = metric['datapoints'].collect {|p| p[0].to_f}

    unless datapoints.empty?
      avg = average(datapoints)

      if !config[:crit].nil? && avg > config[:crit]
        return [2, "#{metric['target']} is #{avg}"]
      elsif !config[:warn].nil? && avg > config[:warn]
        return [1, "#{metric['target']} is #{avg}"]
      end
    end
    [0, nil]
  end

  def run
    body =
      begin
        uri = URI("http://#{config[:host]}/render?format=json&target=#{config[:target]}&from=#{config[:period]}")
        res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
        res.body
      rescue Exception => e
        warning "Failed to query graphite: #{e.inspect}"
      end

    status = 0
    message = ''
    data =
      begin
        JSON.parse(body)
      rescue
        []
      end

    unknown "No data from graphite" if data.empty?

    data.each do |metric|
      s, msg = danger(metric)

      message += "#{msg} " unless s == 0
      status = s unless s < status
    end

    if status == 2
      critical message
    elsif status == 1
      warning message
    end
    ok
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you want to eliminate nils before doing collect, you can do

```
metric['datapoints'].reject { |p| p.nil? }.collect {|p| p[0].to_f}
```

instead of

```
metric['datapoints'].collect {|p| p[0].to_f}
```

BTW, you `average` can also be rewritten as

```
def average(a)
  a.reduce(0,:+)/a.size
end
```

Comment: That's the moment you fall in love with Ruby collections.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array#compact` which does exactly that:

```
["a", nil, "b", nil, "c", nil].compact
#=> [ "a", "b", "c" ]
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-compact